# Removing anchor tags from URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a bunch of anchor tags for mobile browsing due to a very long page but when the anchor tag is clicked it adds it to the url. Here is a small mock,

```
<a href="#anchor">page down</a>

<span id="anchor"></span>
```

How can I retain the anchor functionality and prevent #anchor being added to the url?

Cheers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [scrollTop](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) to achieve the same effect:

```
$('.js-hook--page-down').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#anchor").offset().top - 200
    }, 1500);
});
```

And the HTML:

```
<a class="js-hook--page-down">page down</a>

<span id="anchor"></span>
```

You need a new js hook for each of the page anchors though.

Answer (score 0):

It's up to you how you'd want to go about it, but I would do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(window).on('hashchange', function(e){ // listen if hashtag is being added to the URL

    location.href = location.href.replace(location.hash,"") //replace it with nothing
    console.log("bam!"); //enjoy it

});

</script>
```

Comment: This kinda works. When you click on the link to it jumps down to the anchor as epxected, then it removes the #... from the url but drags the page back to the top when its done. Looks like it refreshes the page when the script is done

Answer (score 0):

@DGibbs I took your code an modified it so that rather than having to write it out for each anchor on the page you can use this instead

```
$('.js-anchor').click(function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        var anchor = $(this).text();

        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('#' + anchor).offset().top
        }, 1500);
    });
```

Maybe this will help someone else too. For reference the html looks like this

```
<a class="js-anchor">Top</a>


<span id="Top"></span>
```

Obviously with this code your anchor id must match the text inside the link for it to work

Answer (score -1):

Add `click` event listener to your links and use `preventDefault`.

```
$('.mylink').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

This will stop the links from modifying the urls.

Comment: Tried this method, it works in the sense it stops the url being modified but it also prevents the page being moved to the anchor