# Attempting to remove anchor tags from the URL

Tags: html, nav

Situation: I want to remove the anchor tags ( #tag ) from the end of the URL

What I have tried: I have been following "https://www.finsweet.com/hacks/15/"  and "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34175285/removing-anchor-tags-from-url". Its not working out very well though.

Code:

My snippet from the top nav bar

```
              <ul class="nav">
                <li class="scroll-to-section">
                  <a href="#top" class="active">Home</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
```

My use of Id

```
<div class="main-banner header-text" id="top">
```

Maybe the way i approached the edits to the navigation bar is wrong.. but im not sure what i need to to do to achieve the goal. Or how I used the classes and IDs is possibly incorrect?

--- Edit 1 ---

this is the snipper of the script im attempting to use to remove the anchor tag from the URL bar of a brower.

```
$("#js-anchor").click(function (evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  var anchor = $(this).text();

  $("html, body").animate(
    {
      scrollTop: $("#" + anchor).offset().top,
    },
    1500
  );
});
```

And the html im looking at

```
        <li class="scroll-to-section">
          <a id="js-anchor" href="#testimonials" class="active"
            >staff</a>
        </li>
```

The experment on it is here:

https://the-md.studio/indexhash.html

EDIT2
My new attempt

```
        <li class="scroll-to-section">
          <a  href="#top" class="scroll-to active">Home</a>
        </li>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  // get the anchor link buttons
  const menuBtn = $(".scroll-to");
  // when each button is clicked
  menuBtn.click(() => {
    // set a short timeout before taking action
    // so as to allow hash to be set
    setTimeout(() => {
      // call removeHash function after set timeout
      removeHash();
    }, 5); // 5 millisecond timeout in this case
  });

  // removeHash function
  // uses HTML5 history API to manipulate the location bar
  function removeHash() {
    history.replaceState(
      "",
      document.title,
      window.location.origin + window.location.pathname + window.location.search
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: Where do you want to remove that? Like is you code in the browser? Can you show your code?

Comment: @TheFool I have a dev webspace here: https://the-md.studio

Comment: You posted zero code where you try to remove the href. If you remove the href it is not a valid link anymore (in your example) So what are you trying to achieve, and HOW?

Comment: @cloned Apologies about that. I basically followed those two links i provided with no results. Basically in the browser URL bar it shows anchor tag such as  'index.html#tag'. My aim is to remove the anchor portion of the URL bar when navigating. I will create a seperate page to show it in action when i can. Thanks

Comment: Don't create a seperate page somewhere on the internet add this example to your question. You can create a snipped which shows your behavirour.

Comment: @cloned Ok done, Ive added what i tried to do as an edit. Basically I tried to use a class and ID and it breaks the navigation when using the script i provided. Also the anchor are still present in the URL bar.

Comment: You want the HREF attribute and not the TEXT of the element you click on.

Comment: @cloned Could you explain that a bit more for me sorry? And how it would work?

Answer (score 0):

Just saw this Q. I guess this is what you tried to ask:

```
// first: get the full url

var hash_url      = window.location.href; 

// second: simply do a split
// can't go wrong here, because url's that show content are always in correct format

hash_url = hash_url.split('#'); var clean_url = hash_url[0];

alert(clean_url);
```

There's your clean url!